# Visit a page one time, but have separate it blocks in Capybara/RSpec

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm writing some RSpec tests with Capybara in a Rails app and I can use some advice.  I'd like to load the app's home page and then test that certain elements are present on the page.  To do that, I'm writing something like

```
context "Logo is present" do
  it "is configured properly" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page.find("a.logo")[:alt]).to have_content("blah")
    expect(page.find("a.title")[:alt]).to have_content("title")
    ... 4 more expect lines here ...
  end
end
```

I don't particularly like having a bunch of these expect statements in the same `it` block.  I'd rather have separate it blocks and do something like this:

```
context "Logo is present" do
  before(:all) {visit root_path}
  it "has a valid alt" do
    expect(page.find("a.logo")[:alt]).to have_content("blah")
  end

  it "has a valid title" do
    expect(page.find("a.title")[:alt]).to have_content("title")    
  end

  ... 4 more it lines here ...
end
```

The problem is the call to `before(:all) {visit root_path}`.  I had hoped that would run one time before all the `it` blocks.  Unfortunately, it looks like Capybara tears down the page after the first `it` block is run, so all `it` blocks fail except the first one.

Is there a way I can visit a page one time and have multiple `it` blocks that use that page?  I'm trying to avoid paying the price of visiting the page multiple times when having separate `it` blocks.

Comment: Would be so nice if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - the whole point of rspec tests is that they are isolated from each other.  Also, the type of tests you're showing really seem more like they should be view specs (the capybara matchers should be available in view specs) than feature specs.